# In the new Google Hangouts, is there any way to change the emoticon set?

Tags: google-hangouts

The new Google Hangouts replaced the normal Google Chat ASCII-ish emoticons with somewhat disturbed looking gumdrops. Is there any way to change this emoticon set, or even put it back to how it was before? Note that I just want to change the way *I* see it, I'm not trying to give myself new emoticons to use in chat.

Answer (score 6):

In Firefox, add the following rules to your [userContent.css](https://superuser.com/questions/318912/how-to-override-the-css-of-a-site-in-firefox-with-usercontent-css)

```
@-moz-document domain(google.com) {
    .Pt span { opacity: 1 !important; width: auto !important; }
    .Pt div { display: none !important; }
}
```

This should remove the image and display the Unicode equivalent instead.
What you actually see is dependent on your font support.

If you want to replace them with a different set of images (and have a lot of patience), you can add the following rules instead, for each one you want to change.

```
@-moz-document domain(google.com) {
    .e1f60a { background: url('<path to replacement>') !important; } /* :) */
}
```

The class for each one can be found by inspecting the DOM of the selection menu.

The old static sprite sheets are <del>currently here: [set 1](https://mail.google.com/mail/im/emoticons/1/s1.png) [set 2 & 3](https://mail.google.com/mail/im/emoticons/1/s.png) [set 4](https://mail.google.com/mail/im/emoticons/1/s3.png)</del> no longer available. Unfortunately the animated ones were done with JavaScript rather than a GIF, so can't be replicated easily.

Comment: Will this only happen in Google Hangouts, or will it trigger on emoticons in other places as well?

Comment: Edited to address that. The class that Google's using is pretty nondescript, so I should have done that to start with.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Chrome? I really like the replacement option.

Comment: @SaintWacko http://superuser.com/q/52967/113004

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [Vulcan extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vulcan/ccmlomkjlnhbjdjcgekbjgmmfkidnobh) if you are using Google Chrome. Its purpose is to

> Convert emoticons in Google Hangouts to their text equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

For Chrome on a desktop, you can try [this plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vulcan/ccmlomkjlnhbjdjcgekbjgmmfkidnobh) to transform the default blobs into their text versions. It's not a perfect solution (try ;_; and ;( for example), but nonetheless an improvement IMO.